# prevent AJAX success result to download file or open

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this jquery to make a post request:

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function (e) {

        $('#modal_processing').modal('show');
        $('#modal_body_process').html("Please wait while we are processing your request. This message will automatically close when request successfully completed.");
        $('#modal_title_process').html("Processing...");

        $.ajax({

            url: '@Url.Action("AddNew", "Home")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                Name: $('#txtEmail').val(),
                Project: $('#cbProject').val(),
                Gender: $('#cbGender').val(),
                Level: $('#cbLevel').val(),
                ShiftStart: $('#txtShiftStart').val(),
                ShiftEnd: $('#txtShiftEnd').val(),
                GeoId: $('#cbGeo').val(),
                TowerId: $('#cbTower').val(),
                ProcessId: $('#cbProcess').val(),
                PrimaryTeamId: $('#cbPrimaryTeam').val(),
                RegionId: $('#cbRegion').val(),
                WBSId: $('#cbWBS').val(),
            },                
            dataType: "json",                
            success: function (response) {

                $('#modal_body_process').html("New user has been successfuly added.");
                $('#modal_title_process').html("Successful!");

                setTimeout(function () {          

                    $('#modal_processing').modal('hide');

                }, 3000);

            },
            error: function (resp) {
                $('#modal_body_process').html("Please fill out all required fields.");
                $('#modal_title_process').html("Error");

                setTimeout(function () {                        

                    $('#modal_processing').modal('hide');

                }, 3000);

                alert("Error");
            }


        });

    });
```

in my controller, i have this:

```
if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
        ModelState.Clear();
    return Json(result.StatusCode, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
return View(model);
```

my problem is, everytime the result is success, it always prompting me to download the json file (IE 11) and for mozilla, it opens the json file.

how can i prevent this?

Comment: What is your element with `id="btnAdd"`? Your not cancelling its default action, so you also making a normal post in addition to the ajax.

Comment: here it is:  <input id="btnAdd" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" style="width:200px" />

if i include e.preventdefault(), my client validation is not working.

Comment: Add `e.preventDefault();` as the first line in your script so you do not make a normal submit

Comment: @StephenMuecke, if i add that, my client validation is not working, i mean, the validation message errors are not displaying.

Comment: what is your default data return type. in asp.net it is XML formater by default, have you changed it?

Comment: Then you need to handle the `.submit()` event of the form, not the `.click()` event of your button, and your use `if(!$(this).valid()) { return; }` to cancel the ajax call if its not valid (and you still need `e.preventDefault();` to cancel the normal submit

Comment: @AayQue it is json.

Comment: @AayQue - that has nothing to do with the issue (OP is making a normal submit in addition to the ajax call)

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you provide me a sample on how to do it? I don't get it, if i include the e.preventdefault(), the validation error messages is not displaying and if e.preventdefault() is added, the validation error messages is now showing.

Comment: Read my previous comment - its `$('form').submit(function(e) { ...` NOT `$('#btnAdd').click(function (e) {`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you so much! It works like a charm!